# is python dict.items() threadsafe?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

Python raises an exception if a dictionary changes its size during iteration using `iteritems()`.

I am hit by this problem since my program is *multithreaded* and there are cases that I need to iterate over the `dict` while another thread is adding keys into the `dict`.

Fortunately, I don't need the iteration to be very precise on every element in the `dict`. Therefore I am thinking to use `items()` instead of `iteritems()` to do the iteration. I think `items()` makes a static snapshot of the `dict` and I would work around the problem.

My question is: does `items()` raises an exception if the `dict` size is changing at the same time with `items()` execution?

thanks

Comment: My advice: When in doubt, use a lock :-)

Comment: Presumably items() will have to iterate over the the dictionary as part of constructing its snapshot.  So calling items() won't solve the problem, only move the problem from your code into the implementation of the items() method.  A better solution would be to serialize access to the dictionary using a mutex.

Comment: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm says that dict.keys() is atomic, it is strange to me that items() is not. In the same article, it says that "L1[i:j] = L2" is atomic but "L[i] = L[j]" not, which is strange too. Can I trust that article?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3 (it makes a huge difference in this case)? In Python 2 `items()` gives you a *new* list of tuples for each call, hence if `items()` itself is atomic (note: it takes the GIL) your iteration is, too. But anyway: When in doubt use a lock.

Answer (score 2):

This answer pertains to *CPython*'s implementation of *Python 2* and *Python 3*.

Since the `items()` method is implemented purely in *C* without releasing the [`GIL`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) beforehand or during its execution, no other thread may acquire it and the underlying data structure remains unchanged while this method is executed.

Thus, the invocation of the `items()` method in *Python 2* and in *Python 3* is guaranteed to succeed.

However, while the operations performed on the returned object are thread-safe in *Python 2*, they are not in *Python 3*.

### *Python 2*

The [returned object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) is a copy of the dictionary’s list of `(key, value)` pairs. As such, it is decoupled from the dictionary and operations performed on the dictionary can't affect the copy in hand.

Though, it's worth noting that the items themselves aren't copies of the original items so care should be taken when dealing with mutable items.

### *Python 3*

The [returned object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) is a view object. As such, certain operations performed on it might fail, as detailed in [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may
> raise a `RuntimeError` or fail to iterate over all entries.